# How to flash stock ROM using TWRP on Tecno Spark K7, leaving TWRP intact

Tags: rom-flashing, twrp, 7.0-nougat, stock-rom, mediatek

What are the right steps of `flashing stock ROM using TWRP` **(`Tecno Spark K7, Android 7.0 Nougat, TWRP v3.0.2`)**, and **still have `TWRP Recovery` on the phone, after the process**.
I already have the phone backed up and have the stock ROM as a zip file.

Answer (score 0):

you need a linux machine for converting sparse image into raw partition image

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools-fsutils android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot  
simg2img system.img system.ext4
```

connect phone in twrp

```
adb push system.ext4 /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system
```

if file smaller than < 4 GiB you can rename to system.emmc.win, copy to sdcard and restore from twrp directly, or manually restore from built-in terminal

```
cat /external_sd/system.emmc.win > /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system
```

repeat this for vendor/odm (if exist). boot.img is already in raw format and can be renamed into boot.emmc.win directly

your data and internal storage is maybe encrypted, if you want to backup you need to adb pull /dev/block/dm-0 or /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata + /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/metadata
or
make twrp backup and adb pull -p -a /sdcard

Comment: `find /dev/block -name by-name`

Comment: https://unetbootin.github.io